# Build Lualatex in Sublime

Tags: luatex, sublime-text

My subime-text buildsettings now set to pdflatex, I want to build lualatex file.
How can I change the setting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Supposing that you are using the LaTeXTools:

> **TeX engine selection** is supported. If the first line of the current
>   file consists of the text `%!TEX program = <program>`, where `program` is
>   `pdflatex`, `lualatex` or `xelatex`, the corresponding engine is selected.
>   If no such directive is specified, `pdflatex` is the default. Multi-file
>   documents are supported: the directive must be in the root (i.e.
>   master) file. Also, for compatibility with TeXshop, you can use
>   `TS-program` instead of `program`. **Note**: for this to work, you must **not**
>   customize the `"command"` option in `LaTeX.sublime-settings`. If you do,
>   you will not get this functionality.

To be found in the ReadMe of https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools